# Exercise 4.9 in Eisenbud

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> $R$ is a positively graded ring such that $R_{0}$ is local, and let $P$ be its maximal homogeneous ideal. Now suppose $I\subset R$ is an ideal, and $x\in P$ is an element such that $x$ is a nonzerodivisor on $R/I$. Show that any minimal set of generators for $I$ maps to a minimal generating set for the image of $I$ in $R/(x)$

The question upon is the second part of the original problem. I have figured out the first part in which $R$ is a local ring and $P$ is its maximal ideal.

My ideals are as follows:
suppose $S$ is a minimal set of generators for $I$, and
$S'\subsetneqq S$ is a minimal set of generators for $(I+(x))/(x)$. Choose a $s_{0} 
\in S-S'$, then there are some $r_{i}' \in R$ and some
$s_{i}' \in S_{0}$ such that $\Sigma r_{i}' s_{i}' + rx=s_{0}$ where $r\in R$.
Now $rx\in I$,and the hypothesis on $x$ infers that  $r\in I$. Then we can write $r$
as $r=\Sigma r_{i}s_{i}$. Now $s_{0}$ must be included in $s_{i}$, otherwise
$s_{0}$ can be represented by other generators in $S$. So
$(1-r_{0}x)s_{0}=\Sigma r_{i}'s_{i}'+\Sigma r_{i}s_{i}$. If $P$ is maximal and
$R$ is local, then because $(1-r_{0}x)$ is a unit, we are done by timing $(1-r_{0}x)^{-1}$ on both
sides.

But the difficulty is that $P$ is only a maximal homogeneous ideal, so only the $0$th-degree component of $1-r_{0}x$ is invertible. Meanwhile, I have no ideal about how to use the graded condition of $R$.

Could anyone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved it.

Compare the degree of left and right side of the equation
$$s_{0}=\Sigma r_{i}'s_{i}'+\Sigma r_{i}xs_{i}+r_{0}xs_{0}$$
The components of degree higher than the maximun degree of $s_{0}$ cancel in the right side so after a suitable replacement of $r_{i}'$, $r_{i}x$,$r_{0}x$ by
a sum of its homogenous components we can assume that
$$\text{deg}(r_{i}')+\text{deg}(s_{i}')\leq 
\text{deg}(s_{0})$$
$$\text{deg}(r_{i}x)+\text{deg}(s_{i})\leq 
\text{deg}(s_{0})$$
$$\text{deg}(r_{0}x)+\text{deg}(s_{0})\leq 
\text{deg}(s_{0})$$
Where $\text{deg}(r)$ denotes the maximal degree of $r\in R$
(the $x$  upon may not be the orignal $x$, but that dosen't matter).
Notice that
$$\text{deg}(r_{0}x)+\text{deg}(s_{0})\leq 
\text{deg}(s_{0})$$
we get $\text{deg}(r_{0}x)=0$, so $(1-r_{0}x)$ is invertible.
Because now we have
$$(1-r_{0}x)s_{0}=\Sigma r_{i}'s_{i}'+\Sigma r_{i}xs_{i}$$
we are done.